# Ruby On Rails : AJAX and Submit Request Running Parallely

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is My code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @video do |form| %>
    <div class="form-inputs"> 
    <%= form.input :title, id: :video_title %>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea id="textarea1" name="video[description]" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
       <label for="textarea1">Description</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <label for="spaceTags">Tags</label>
    <div id="spaceTags" class="chips chips-placeholder"></div>
    <%= form.label :movie %>
    <%= form.file_field :movie %>
    <%= form.label :preview_images%>
    <%= form.file_field :preview_images, multiple: true %>
  <p>
  <input type="checkbox" name=video[published] id="test5" />
  <label for="test5">Publish Video</label>
</p>
 <div class="form-actions" onclick="fetch();">
    <%= form.submit%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

and my javascript code is :

```
$('#textarea1').trigger('autoresize');
$('.chips').material_chip();
$('.chips-placeholder').material_chip({
   placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
   secondaryPlaceholder: '+Tag',
});
function fetch(){
 var x = $('#spaceTags').material_chip('data');
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "/videos",
    data: {"sarthak":JSON.stringify(x)},
    success : function(){alert ("Success!")},
    error : function(data){alert(data.message)}
  });
  }
```

when i try to submit the form it makes the call to same action in both the cases.Is there some way by which i can delay the form submission until the AJAX call gets executed or any other way by which i can resolve this issue.

Comment: Bad to name your function `fetch`... it already exist on the global scope... you are either overriding it or preventing using it in a scope. Should be name something along: `getVideos` calling a fetch function can fetch anything if you only look at the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault` which will stop the normal execution of the form and just trigger your `fetch` method.

You can change your `fetch` method to:

```
function fetch(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // the rest of your code
}
```

Then, in your ajax `success` promise, you can handle anything else you want, even submitting the form again if you wish

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "/videos",
    data: {"sarthak":JSON.stringify(x)},
    success : function(){
        alert ("Success!"); 
        $('form').submit() 
    },
    error : function(data){alert(data.message)}
  });
```